# Uniform initialization in C++0x, when to use () instead of {}?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there a rule of thumb to decide when to use the old syntax **`()`** instead of the new syntax **`{}`**?

To initialize a struct:

```
struct myclass
{
    myclass(int px, int py) : x(px), y(py) {}
private:
    int x, y;
};
...
myclass object{0, 0};
```

Now in the case of a `vector` for example, it has many constructors. Whenever I do the following:

```
vector<double> numbers{10};
```

I get a vector of **1** element instead of one with **10** elements as one of the constructors is:

```
explicit vector ( size_type n, const T& value= T(), const Allocator& = Allocator() );
```

My suspicion is that whenever a class defines an `initializer list` constructor as in the case of a vector, it gets called with the **`{}`** syntax.

So, is what I am thinking correct. i.e. **Should I revert to the old syntax only whenever a class defines an initializer list constructor to call a different constructor?** e.g. to correct the above code:

```
vector<double> numbers(10); // 10 elements instead of just one element with value=10
```

Comment: Does that mean that one can break a classes clients when adding initializer list constructors? Ouch.

Comment: No, the initializer constructor does not affect the other constructors in place AFAIK.

Comment: @dribeas: Is that certain. Suppose your class initially has a constructor that takes a single int argument and you happily create instances with the new syntax. If a new constructor gets added that takes `initializer_list<int>`, wouldn't all those objects now be using the added constructor? Unless the examples on the net are out-of-date and declaring a vector with the list should in fact look like `vector<int> v{{2, 1}};` I don't see brackets going anywhere.

Comment: Also, with GCC 4.4.1 it appears that the presence of a constructor taking an `initializer_list` hides all other constructors when one attempts to use `{}` for initialization. For example: `std::vector<int> a, b{a};` fails to compile. I don't know if that is/will be intended, or whether this is just a compiler short-coming. If that is intended, I suppose doing things the old way might often be wise (e.g with templates, should the template type be a container). The new syntax definitely adds value, but it doesn't appear to allow *uniformity*.

Answer (score 10):

I've found the answer in the standard docs([latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n3000.pdf)). Hopefully, I'll try to explain what I understood.

First, if a class defines an initialization list constructor, then it is used whenever suitable:

> **§ 8.5.4 (page 203)**
>
> Initializer-list constructors are
> favored over other constructors in
> list-initialization (13.3.1.7).

I think this is a great feature to have, eliminating the headache associated with the *non-uniform* style :)

Anyway, the only gotcha(which my question is about) is that if you design a class without the initializer constructor, then you add it later you may get surprising result.

Basically, imagine `std::vector` didn't have the initializer list constructor, then the following would create a vector with 10 elements:

```
std::vector<int> numbers{10};
```

By adding the initializer list constructor, the compiler would favor it over the other constructor because of the `{}` syntax. This behavior would happen because the elements of the init-list `{10}` **are** accepted using the init-list constructor. If there is no acceptable conversion, any other constructor shall be used e.g.:

```
std::vector<string> vec{10};
// a vector of 10 elements.
// the usual constructor got used because "{0}"
// is not accepted as an init-list of type string.
```

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this:

http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=cplusplus&seqNum=453&rll=1

The use of a `{}`-style initializers on a variable has no direct mapping to the initialization lists on any constructors of the class.  Those constructor initialization lists can be added/removed/modified without breaking existing callers.

Basically the different behavior of the container is special, and requires special code in that container, specifically a constructor taking a `std::initializer_list`.  For POD and simple objects, you can use `{}` and `()` interchangeably.

Comment: "For POD and simple objects, you can use {} and () interchangeably." No, `()` only works if there is a constructor, which (aside from the copy constructor) disqualifies the object from being POD. `{}` on the other hand still works.