# When should I use uniform initialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, struct

In `C++11` it's possible to initialize an `struct` using uniform initialization like below:

```
struct BasicStruct {
    BasicStruct (int x, double y) : x_{x}, y_{y} {}

private:
    int x_;
    double y_;
};

BasicStruct var1{5, 3.2};
```

Questions:

1. When should I use this syntax `BasicStruct var1{5, 3.2}` instead of calling the constructor like `BasicStruct var1(5, 3.2)`?
2. When should I initialize an attribute like `x_{x}` instead of old fashion way `x_(x)`?

Comment: No, that's a "why" and this is a "when." Seriously folks.

Comment: @Potatoswatter http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1863784/uniform-initialization-in-c0x-when-to-use-instead-of?rq=1 etc.

Comment: @Rapptz OK, now find one with answers that make sense, or are better than the one I added here :)

Comment: @Potatoswatter Your answer doesn't really add anything to the duplicate linked, in my eyes.

Comment: @Rapptz It also explains what the difference is, with quotes from the Standard, without mentioning general best practices. The second answer is completely erroneous.

Answer (score 8):

Use list-initialization when the list is generic and you could substitute another container, such as an array, an aggregate, or a `vector`, without changing its meaning much.

```
// "triplet" may be a struct, an array, or a std::vector,
// but it has at least single-precision floating-point values.
triplet dimensions { 5, 1.2f, static_cast< float >( M_PI ) };
```

If you are constructing a specific class with arguments to a specific constructor, then old-fashioned parens are more appropriate.

One unique feature of initialization with a braced-init-list is that it does not allow *narrowing conversions* which could cause numeric data to be lost, for example the fractional part of a floating-point number or the high bits of a `long`. This helps to flag (or prevent) errors resulting from substitution of e.g. a narrower array type during code refactoring.

Likewise, the other case where `x{ y }` is appropriate is when performing a numeric conversion that you do not with to be lossy. `x( y )` will try really hard to make the conversion, even resorting to a `reinterpret_cast`, and should generally be avoided.

The terminology "uniform initialization" is a bit optimistic, and it does not appear in the standard. It is not appropriate for all cases. Braces generally indicate lists, so it's properly called list-initialization. And that is when it should be used.